# What's an example of traduction?

Tags: meaning

The second definition of "traduction" given by Merriam Webster's website is

> The repetition of a word or one of its derivatives or a term with a change in sense for rhetorical or argumentative effect.

I'm not sure what this means. What is an example of this?

Comment: **traduction** has a range of "more or less related" meanings. The one here is specifically a *rhetorical device*. It just means deliberately using the same word more than once within an utterance, but *with different meanings / allusions associated with the different instances of the word*. Similar to **zeugma** (using a word *once*, but with multiple meanings, usually for humour, as in *John and his driving licence **expired** last week*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example is provided by a jingle (of the non-musical variety) the [BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p0165kxz) used to advertise their BBC iPlayer (catch-up service):

> - *Making the unmissable, unmissable.*

Some might prefer to drop the comma.

The first 'unmissable' means 'too good to miss', and the second 'so easy to access even if you miss the first showing that you need never miss [the programme in question]'.

But this sense of 'traduction' is rarely encountered.

Comment: Well found! I gave up looking for examples when it became apparent that so far as Google is concerned, if I include the word **traduction** (underlined in red by my UK-based spellchecker) in my search terms, I must be French, and I must be trying to find a **translation** of something.

Comment: @FumbleFingers that's the problem I ran into also

Comment: @Timkinsella: I probably already knew it *as a French word* already, but even though I wasn't familiar with the definition as cited by OP here, I understood it perfectly well as soon as I read it. ***But*** - coming up with an actual example isn't easy! Dictionaries give example usages of the word itself, ***not*** examples of utterances which ***exemplify / illustrate*** use of the rhetorical device!

Comment: I would have heard it as a French word -- the word for _translation_ -- and pronounced it in French. I would not have looked it up in an English dictionary. People often use French words, n'est-ce pas?